# Why N+1 and not just N?

Tags: probability

Here's the example. I follow the example up until it says that there are N+1 equally likely outcomes that result in x=y. Why N+1 and not N? I don't really follow the logic. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I can barely read the image because it's so low quality, but: There are $N + 1$ things in the set $\{0, ..., N\}$.

Comment: We count from $0,1,\cdots,$ to $N.$ And that amounts to $N+1.$

Comment: The set containing only zero is {0} and has 1 item. The set containing zero and one is {0,1} and has 2 items. {0,1,2} has three items, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those things that makes much more sense when you try a small example. How many integers are in the set $\{ 0, \ldots, 4 \}$? Well, it's $\{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 \}$, which is $5$ elements.

Comment: Thank you SO much for using an example! I have a hard time grasping stuff like this and this really really helped.